# How to set multiple values for node_options?

Tags: node.js

In my case, I need two values for NODE_OPTIONS:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

I tried:

```
cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 --openssl-legacy-provider umi build
```

But not working.

Comment: Try putting them in quotes: `NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096 --openssl-legacy-provider umi build"`

Comment: not working @jfriend00

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
"build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max_old_space_size=4096 --openssl-legacy-provider\" umi build"
```

in package.json works for me

Answer (score 6):

you can try like this

NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096 --openssl-legacy-provider" umi build

Answer (score 1):

In the `.npmrc` file of your project, you can set

```
node-options="--max_old_space_size=4096 --openssl-legacy-provider"
```

to have as many options as you want, rather than messing around with environment variables.